# Error: C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'newArr'

Tags: c++, массивы, heap, buffer

Код должен создавать множество с размером и значениями, которые введет пользователь. Я хочу расширить массив на 1 значения на куче и вставить в конец char в виде кода ASCII, но Visual Studio подчеркивает строку с `newArr[*size++] = static_cast<int>(name);` говоря: **"Error: C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'newArr'"**. При исполнении программы после выполнения `delete[] arr;` вылетает ошибка **"CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"**

```
#include <iostream>

int SizeOfSet();
void AddName(int* &arr, int* size, const char name);
void Initialize(int* arr, int *size);
void Show(int* arr, int size);

int main()
{
   int findSize = SizeOfSet();
   int* size = &findSize;
   int* A = new int(*size);

   Initialize(A, size);
   AddName(A, size, 'A');
   Show(A, *size);

   return 0;
}

int SizeOfSet()
{
    int size;
    std::cout << "Enter a size of set:\n";
    std::cin >> size;

    return size;
}

void AddName(int* &arr, int* size, const char name)
{
    int* newArr = new int[*size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;

    newArr[*size++] = static_cast<int>(name);

    arr = newArr;
}

void Initialize(int* arr, int* size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код у тебя конечно что-то с чем-то, тут неправильно буквально всё, но давай ответим на твой вопрос.

У тебя массив имеет размер size + 1. Допустим size - 10. Тогда размер массива 11. Максимальный индекс будет 10, т.к массивы у нас с 0. Вот и ответ на вопрос. Вместо *size++, просто *size

Comment: Все равно та же ошибка